# Contact form using nodemailer is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, nodemailer

I have created a contact form and trying to use nodemailer to send the message to my email, but not sure where is the issue.
I created a server.js and put it in the main folder while Mailer.js that contain the form in components

I am not sure how the server know that I want to use the form
this is my first project on React and I think I still don't understand some basics of React

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const app = express();

// View engine setup
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Static folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('contact');
});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
  const output = `
    <p>You have a new contact request</p>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>  
      <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
      <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${req.body.message}</p>
  `;

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL, // generated ethereal user
        pass: process.env.PASSWORD  // generated ethereal password
    },
    tls:{
      rejectUnauthorized:false
    }
  });

  // setup email data with unicode symbols
  let mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.EMAIL, // sender address
      to: email, // list of receivers
      subject: 'Node Contact Request', // Subject line
      text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
      html: output // html body
  };

  // send mail with defined transport object
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
          return console.log(error);
      }
      console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);   
      console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

      res.render('contact', {msg:'Email has been sent'});
  });
  });

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started...'));
```

This is the form

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Mailer.scss";
const Mailer = () =>{

    return (

        <div className="container">
             <div className="section ContactPage">
                <div className="ContactPage-banner">
                    <h1 className="ContactPage-banner__title">Contact Us</h1>
                </div>

        <div className="ContactPage-content">
            <form method="POST" className="form" action="send">
                <div className="row">
                <label className="labels">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" className="input"/>
                </div>

                <div className="row">
                <label className="labels">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" className="input"/>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                <label className="labels">Message</label>                
                <textarea name="message" rows='4' className="input"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Mailer;
```

[image]

this is what I get when I click on SEND

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I could gather, you're posting to the wrong URL.
In your server app, you create a post handler for /send
However, in your React App, you post to /xxxxx/send (You obscured the xxxxx part)

I advise that you replace your

```html
<form method="POST" className="form" action="send">
```

With

```html
<form method="POST" className="form" action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/send">
```

And try again